# If set of matrices {AE, BE,CE,DE} linear independent then E is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd to to get your help.

Let A,B,C,D be matrices in $M_{2}(R)$, prove or disprove the following:

If {AE,BE,CE,DE} are different and linear independent then matrix E is invertible:

This is my try:

Let A,B,C,D matrices, we know that {AE,BE,CE,DE} are different and linear independent.

Then we have have $$a=b=c=d=0$$ so: $$aAE + bBE + cCE + dDE=0$$
Then, $$(aA + bB + cC +dD)E = 0$$
I can conclude that also {A,B,C,D} are linear independent.

But the problem is that I don't know how to continue, because 0 (zero) can't be the product of two invertible matrices so I can't conclude any additional information from this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with $a=...=0$ goes nowhere. Usually you start with arbitrary coefficients and at some point show they must be all zero to get what you want.

This problem itself admits a much easier approach. Since $M_2(\mathbb R)$ has dimension $4$, we know $AE, BE, CE, DE$ forms a basis assuming they are linearly independent. Therefore there exist $a,b,c,d$ such that $aAE + bBE + cCE + d DE = I_2$, and $aA+bB+cC + dD$ is clearly the inverse matrix of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, if $\left\{ AE,BE,CE,DE \right\} $ is linear independent, then we have $E$ is invertible. This problem equal to if $E$ is not invertible, then $\left\{ AE,BE,CE,DE \right\} $ is linear dependent. If $E$ is not invertible, we can write $E$ as $(\vec v_1,\alpha\vec v_1)$, so $AE=(A\vec v_1,\alpha A\vec v_1)$ which is still not inversible, same for $BE$,$CE$ and $DE$. Then we can see we only have $\vec v_1$ is free which only have $2$ elements. So $\left\{ AE,BE,CE,DE \right\} $ must be linear dependent.